# Bound of Mann iterative sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

There is theorem in the book of Charles Chidume "Geometric Properties
of Banach Spaces and Nonlinear Iterations"

My question is: why if the underlined conditions are satisfied {Xn} is bounded (proof is finish)?

Theorem:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57260171/math_question.png

**Edit:**

j(x)∈ J(x), where J(x): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57260171/j.PNG

Comment: I deleted my previous comment since I just realized $Tx$ represents $T(x)$, not some number $T$ times $x$...But I do not know what hte "j" constant (or function) is doing in the theorem (equation 9.8).  So I will not try to answer.

Comment: @Michael, I've added definition of j(x) to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
x_0 = Tx_1\\
x_1 = a_0x_0 + b_0x_0 = (a_0 + b_0)x_0\\
a_0 + b_0 = 1\\
x_0 = x_1 = ... = x_n
$$